# Oracle 9i index error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query:

```
select *
from gps_servicio ser
where ser.id in (select idserv from gps_agentes where idagen = 8073061);
```

This query works perfectly until I make an index in the table gps_agentes, on the field idserv (asc one). If I do that, the query brokes and I get no results from it. Is this a bug?
Both gps_servicio.id and gps_agentes.idserv are number(10,0) fields, and I have a FK on gps_agentes.idserv that points to gps_servicio.id.

Thx for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the results of a query change when you create an index, that indicates a bug, yes.  If you are encountering a bug, you would need to report that to Oracle Support to determine whether the bug you are encountering is already fixed by an existing patch or whether it is a new bug that no one has encountered before.

However, given that you say that you are using 9i, a version of the database that is at least 5 major releases old and has been out of primary support for many years, my wager is that you are running without a support contract and without access to Oracle Support.  Are you at least running the latest patchset of whatever version of Oracle you are using ("9i" covers two major releases, 9.0.1 and 9.2)?

Comment: My oracle version is Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.1.0. I think the last patch is 9.2.0.8, but will be imposible to download without an oracle support account, i think... Anyway, thanks a lot for your time @JustinCave

Comment: @JuanmiOrtegaCortizas - If you don't have a support contract, you won't be able to download patchsets so you'll be stuck with whatever bugs and security holes were in the initial 9.2.0.1 release.  I would hope that upgrading to something that includes support and that has been released in the last decade would be a priority if this is vaguely production-related.